# C array size depending on variable value known at compilation time

Tags: arrays, memory, arduino-c++

I am working on a library to read Serial data from an electric counter. The counter can transmit up to 105 different tags depending on your contract. Because this library could be on lightweight and not powerful embedded systems (typically arduino or esp8266), I am trying to reduce the memory usage to the bare minimum.

To read each tag, my library has a buffer with its length equal the biggest tag value length possible (ranging from 2 bytes to 94 bytes). I would like my library to automatically set the buffer size to the correct value kowning that the user is able to indicate which tag he wants with #define instructions in its main file.

main.cpp

```
#define BASE
#define HCHP
#define OPTARIF

#include "LinkyTIC.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial LinkySerial(13, 15);
LinkyTIC linky(LinkySerial);

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  if(linky.read()){
    int base = linky.GetBASE();
    int hchp = linky.GetHCHP();
    Serial.println(base);
    Serial.println(hchp);
  }
}
```

What I tried :

In my header file, I used a chain of #ifdef to keep the maximum length, but I get the error "the value of variable "max_length" cannot be used as a constant". I tried to cast the value to a constant but it didn't work either.

header.h

```
uint8_t max_length = 8;

#ifdef ADCO
    uint8_t max_length = max_length > 12 ? max_length : 12;
#endif
#ifdef OPTARIF
    uint8_t max_length = max_length > 4 ? max_length : 4;
#endif
#ifdef ISOUSC
    uint8_t max_length = max_length > 2 ? max_length : 2;
#endif
#ifdef BASE
    uint8_t max_length = max_length > 9 ? max_length : 9;
#endif
...

class LinkyTIC {
    public:
         // unrelated stuff

    private:
        // unrelated stuff

        char _buffer_tag[8];            // buffer for the tag name


>>>>    char _buffer_date[max_length];          // buffer for the (optional) tag date. Must be the same length as value because we can't know in advance if it s going to be a date or a value
                          ^^^^^^^^^^  the value of variable "max_length" cannot be used as a constant
>>>>    char _buffer_value[max_length];         // buffer for the tag value
                           ^^^^^^^^^^ the value of variable "max_length" cannot be used as a constant


        char _buffer_checksum[1];       // buffer for the tag checksum

        char _checksum;

        char* _buffers[4] = {_buffer_tag, _buffer_date, _buffer_value, _buffer_checksum};
        uint8_t _buffer_reference_index;
        uint8_t _buffer_index;
...
}
```

The value of max_length can thus be known at compile time, but I can't figure out a way to create my array using its value.

What would be the best way to achieve what I want to do ? Because flash is also an issue, I would rather avoid using std::vector.

Comment: That code is C++, not C. And for C++ you have `std::vector`.

Comment: It's either `std::vector`, or your own dynamic memory handling with pointers (which will increase your development time, perhaps even considerably).

Comment: You have variables both `max_length` and also `max_lenght`.  That might confuse some people.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you ! The tag c++ has been removed then re-added. I edited my post to change header.h code to Cpp too.
For std::vector, I am afraid it would increase flash usage for something I do not necessarily need, hence my question on SO :)

Comment: @abelenky oops sorry, that was a typo :)

Comment: Are your character arrays supposed to be used for strings? Why not use the Arduino's own [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class?

Comment: just code it the normal way and the compiler will optimize the code for the constant doing the calculation at compile time and removing unused code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because i am not sure my end user will use arduino's SDK ! I much prefer having a general purpose library if I m able to (plus I love challenging myself to learn new things)

Comment: @Juraj unfortunately, it didn't seem like it. The RAM and flash usage weren't changing depending on which tags I was calling.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options using preprocessor macros and `#if` statements, depending on what your requirements are, which you have not clearly stated. One example is:

```
#define MaximumLength 8

#if defined ADCO
    #if MaximumLength > 12
        #undef MaximumLength
        #define MaximumLength 12
    #endif
#endif
#if defined OPTARIF
    #if MaximumLength > 4
        #undef MaximumLength
        #define MaximumLength 4
    #endif
#endif
#if defined ISOUSC
    #if MaximumLength > 2
        #undef MaximumLength
        #define MaximumLength 2
    #endif
#endif
#if defined BASE
    #if MaximumLength > 9
        #undef MaximumLength
        #define MaximumLength 9
    #endif
#endif

uint8_t max_length = MaximumLength; // If this variable is still desired.
…

        char _buffer_date[MaximumLength];
```

Comment: Oh, that s clever, thank you for these new preprocessor macros. Your solution will definitely work ! I have no requirements but guidelines to minimize RAM and flash memory usage as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to define your variable either `const` or `consexpr`.
Since you code already has error, you can't redefine variable with same name, I'm not sure what you intended to do, but something like this should work:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

// Uncomment line(s) below to check behavior
//#define ADCO
//#define OPTARIF
//#define ISOUSC
//#define BASE

const uint8_t def_max_length = 8;

#ifdef ADCO
    const uint8_t max_length = std::max<uint8_t>(def_max_length, 12);
#elif defined(OPTARIF)
    const uint8_t max_length = std::max<uint8_t>(def_max_length, 4);
#elif defined(ISOUSC)
    const uint8_t max_length = std::max<uint8_t>(def_max_length, 2);
#elif defined(BASE)
    const uint8_t max_length = std::max<uint8_t>(def_max_length, 9);
#else
    const uint8_t max_length = def_max_length;
#endif

char buffer[max_length];

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::size(buffer) << std::endl;
}
```

If you need to check all defines independently, then you can define one variable for each define, something like:

```
#ifdef ADCO
    const uint8_t max_length_adco = 12;
#else
    const uint8_t max_length_adco = 0;
#ednif
```

And then just get maximum of all these variables:

```
const uint8_t max_length = std::max({def_max_length, max_length_adco, max_length_optarif, max_length_isousc, max_length_base});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I guess the if; elif chain would only work if I sort my tags by value length (the user can ask for multiple tags so if;else would only take the first one that is defined). I did not think of that but that could be an easy way to fix my problem !

Comment: I just thought of the fact that in your second solution (the one I was going for), the compiler would probably have written every variables to the flash memory despite them not being used anywhere else in the code.

That let me with your first solution if I sort everything by decreasing value length or Eric Postpischil's solution using preprocessor macros.

Comment: If you make these variables `static` or define them in anonymous namespace, then most probably compiler will optimeze out these variables. But you can check this in generated code.